# onKeyDown is not invoked while using soft keypads

Tags: android

My xml code for my Activity is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TO add Key Event for this I have coded in main activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
/*  e1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i("keycode","Inside on key");
            //char a=event.getDisplayLabel();
            char a = (char)event.getUnicodeChar();
      Log.i("keycode",Character.toString(a));               
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                Log.i("keycode",Integer.toString(keyCode));
                Log.i("keycode",(e1.getText()).toString());
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });*/


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("key","KeyPressed"+Integer.toString(keyCode));
    Log.i("keycode",(e1.getText()).toString());
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
    {
        Log.i("key1","KeyPressed A");
        Log.i("keycode1",(e1.getText()).toString());

        return true;
    }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Closing Activity")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();    
    }

})
.setNegativeButton("No", null)
.show();

}


}
```

when I press A from the soft Keypad...the method onKeyDown or onKeyUp is Not called...somebody say me the way to invoke these methods when i press alphabet in soft Keypad..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

*As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version. Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key presses.*

Thus most keys do not generate any **KeyEvent**.
The only way to capture which key is pressed is through **TextWatcher**.