# Custom AdapterView - onKeyDown not called

Tags: android

I've created a custom `ListView` by extending `AdapterView` and I'd like to handle key events inside of this View. I've overridden `onKeyDown`, but don't ever see it called. I even tried overriding `dispatchKeyEvent` and that never gets called either. I've also made my View focusable with `setFocusable(true)`.

Also, I'm a bit confused as to which view actually DOES have focus. In HierarchyView, every single view in the tree says hasFocus = false.

How can I receive key events in my View?

Comment: You want to handle softkeyboard events? See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476079/onkeydown-is-not-invoked-while-using-soft-keypads/15485248#15485248

Comment: @HoanNguyen no. hard key events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can answer my own question here.

Taking a look at `AdapterView`, you can see that it overrides setFocusable with the following implementation:

```
 @Override
    public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
        final T adapter = getAdapter();
        final boolean empty = adapter == null || adapter.getCount() == 0;

        mDesiredFocusableState = focusable;
        if (!focusable) {
            mDesiredFocusableInTouchModeState = false;
        }

        super.setFocusable(focusable && (!empty || isInFilterMode()));
    }
```

As you can see from the final call to super.setFocusable there, the View will not be focusable if there's no data bound yet from the adapter (meaning the adapter is either null or its is <= 0).

So to resolve this, simply add `setFocusable(true)` at the end of your `setAdapter()` implementation.

Comment: I had the same problem with onKey not being called when ListView is empty. It only worked when i set both setFocusable() and setFocusableInTouchMode() to true, but I would never figure it out without reading your answer first. +1 up!